# Strange layout of the HDF tables from pandas.HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

When I output a `pandas.DataFrame` as a table in HDFStore:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}, index=range(2))
with pd.HDFStore("test.hdf5") as store:
    store.put("test", df, format="table")
```

I get the following layout when reading in ViTables:
[image: ViTables]

I can correctly read it back with `pandas.read_hdf()`, but I find the data difficult to read: It's in these blocks, and the name of the columns is hidden by a `values_block_0` label.

Is there a way to have a more intuitive layout in the HDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `datacolumns=True` in `store.put()` arguments gives a better layout:

[image: ViTables]